# Concat value of all elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml like the below structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>
     <book>
          <title lang="eng">Harry Potter</title>
          <price>29.99</price>
     </book>

     <book>
           <title lang="eng">Learning XML</title>
           <price>39.95</price>
     </book>
</bookstore>
```

I have extracted all the `title` nodes as `<xsl:variable name="titles" select="/bookstore/book/title"/>`. Now, I would like to  concat these titles enclosing each of them in single quotes and then separating them with commas and store them in a variable so that the output looks like: `'Harry Potter','Learning XML'`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A known list of values can be "put together" by `concat()`. But in your case you do not know how many items belong to your list (in titels), the only possibility in xlst-1.0 is to  iterate to the elements (`for-each` or `apply-templates` and concat them.

Try this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="titles" select="/bookstore/book/title"/>
    <xsl:variable name="titles_str" >
        <xsl:for-each select="$titles" >
            <xsl:if test="position() > 1 ">, </xsl:if>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$titles_str"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change your titles variable with this one:

```
  <xsl:variable name="titles">
    <xsl:for-each select="/bookstore/book/title">
      <xsl:text>'</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

to get desired output:

```
'Harry Potter', 'Learning XML'
```